# Simple script hangs creating and/or saving figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running Python 2.7.11+ and `matplotlib` 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

The very simple script shown below hangs at either of the three lines marked. If I leave all lines un-commented, it will hang on the first one. If I comment it out, it will hang on the second one. Same with the third one.

No error or warning shows, it just never goes beyond any of those lines.

What could be the reason for this? A bad matplotlib installation? How can I check this, because it seems like it is properly installed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print 'Hangs here v'
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))

plt.scatter([0.3, 2.7], [0.5, 1.5])

print 'Also hangs here v'
plt.show()

print 'Also here v'
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: What backend for `matplotlib` are you using?

Comment: No idea, I'm using whatever the default is after a brand new installation. I just installed both the OS and matplotlib. I never had to tweak this before to make it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this was an issue with the backend. I'm not sure why though, since I never had to mess with this after a new installation like this one

I tried the solution mentioned here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/08/24/resolved-matplotlib-figures-not-showing-up-or-displaying/ but it did not work.

I also tried installing via:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

but it did not work also.

At some point something got installed and I could successfully install matplotlib via:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

and use it properly.

So my recommendation is: try all methods of installation listed, one of them apparently fixes the issue.